# Filter relevant SOAP request from WSDL url

Tags: java, oracle, soap, cloud

I'm using SOAP WSDL url for java application

https://egpb-test.fin.ap1.oraclecloud.com/finArTrxnsInvoices/InvoiceService/types/?WSDL

It contains so many requests. But I need only one request called as "createSimpleInvoice". Is it possible to filter that request only from the given url?

Comment: "I'm using SOAP WSDL url for java application" - What does this mean? Are you implementing a service according to the wsdl? Are you consuming the web service that this wsdl defines?

Comment: Sorry, url must be this
https://egpb-test.fin.ap1.oraclecloud.com/finArTrxnsInvoices/InvoiceService?WSDL

Comment: There is a stand alone java application with java swings. And from this application I need to call previous mentioned web service.  But I need only one request called as "createSimpleInvoice". Is it possible to filter that request only from the given url?

Comment: Yes I'm consuming the web service that this wsdl defines

Comment: You can't "Filter".  the WSDL file is a structural document detailing the data model and operations.  Why do you think you need to "filter" anything?

Comment: it contains so many request and I have used only one request
then call that request but I have got this error in java;
Two classes have the same XML type name

Comment: That's why i need to filter the unnecessary request;
I have used wsimport to load java classes is there any possibility to filter those packages